Interrupting busy worker process
I am trying to benchmark an algorithm I developed. To this end, I run the algorithm on several instances and measure time, memory, other numbers... For each instance, I create a new process; partly because I don't wait the entire benchmark to die if one instance was too big. The host process (and thus all workers) os run with a some ulimit on virtual memory. However, I also want to limit the time for an instance, and just kill it when it's done. I don't want to do this with a prlimit on the worker process, because I don't want to include some expensive setup in this limit. I came up with the following mockup:
using Distributed
addprocs(1)
@everywhere function f()
  sleep(10)
end
pid = workers()[1]
t = remotecall(f, pid)
if timedwait(()->isready(t), 2) == :timed_out
  println("Interrupted worker")
  rmprocs(pid)
else
  print("Worker gave ", fetch(t))
end

which kills the worker after two seconds as expected.
However, if I replace f by
@everywhere function f()
  rand(10000, 10000)^2
end

Then it does not work anymore; i.e., the worker just terminates when its expensive work is done. This made me wonder if the benchmarked task in the worker process has to yield control intermittently for the interface with the main process to do stuff. This seems kind of useless for my application.
Am I seeing this right? If yes, what can I do instead; if not, why doesn't the second case work as expected?
P.S.: If relevant, running workers with multiple threads seems not to be an option, because I use a library that is known not to work properly in a multithreaded julia process.

A problem in the given code is that isready blocks waiting for a reply from a remote Future.  This problem and a solution are described in the documentation for isready(::Future):

If the argument Future is owned by a different node, this call will block to wait for the answer. It is recommended to wait for rr in a separate task instead or to use a local Channel as a proxy:
p = 1
f = Future(p)
errormonitor(@async put!(f, remotecall_fetch(long_computation, p)))
isready(f)  # will not block


So using a local Future and an async task to set its value:
using Distributed

addprocs(1)
@everywhere function fun()
  rand(10000, 10000)^2
end

pid = workers()[1]
fut = Future()
@async put!(fut, remotecall_fetch(fun, pid))
if timedwait(()->isready(fut), 2) == :timed_out
  println("Interrupting worker")
  rmprocs(pid)
else
  print("Worker gave ", fetch(fut))
  rmprocs(pid)
end

Here the async is only in the main process.  So the main process will use multiple threads, but not the worker process.

Being able to read all the relevant docs is a blessing... good that this is actually described there!

Malt.jl might provide one possible alternative workaround for Distributed.jl.  Malt.remote_call returns a local task rather than a remote Future, so istaskdone does not block.
import Malt.Malt
import Distributed.@everywhere

w = Malt.DistributedStdlibWorker()

@everywhere function f()
    rand(10000, 10000)^2
end

t = Malt.remote_call(f, w)

if timedwait(()->istaskdone(t), 2) == :timed_out
  println("Interrupted worker")
  Malt.stop(w)
else
  print("Worker gave ", fetch(t))
  Malt.stop(w)
end


But the 15 seconds are a parameter to stop, right? Also, do you know what uses the Distributed stdlib as a backend means in the documentation to Malt.DistributedStdlibWorker()? How is it different from Worker()?

Lastly, how can I send the @everywhere to the specific worker? @everywhere has an optional argument for the (pseudo-)pid.

The Distributed.jl backend and the Malt.jl backend use different communication protocols.

@everywhere [1, pid] function f(); ...; end  defines f in both process 1 and in the worker specified by pid.  (Maybe that is needed for them to communicate about f.)
